# Alarm Notification is displayed as soon as alarm is set, even though time is future time

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I am facing a problem in setting a alarm, I am giving future time to the alarmManager.Set method but as soon as alarm  gets triggered I am getting the notification instead of receiving the notification at the specified time. Please let me know what mistake am I doing. This is the first time I am working on alarm so please let me know my mistakes. All suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

My Alarm Setting method:

I am taking the entered time by the user and formatting the time and giving it to the alarmManager.Set method:

```
String givenDateString = dateTime;
    Log.d("Pana", "The value of Date Time is " +dateTime);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0530"));
    try {
        Date mDate = sdf.parse(givenDateString);
        timeInMilliseconds = mDate.getTime();
        Log.d("Pana ", "Date in milli :: " + timeInMilliseconds);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




    // create an Intent and set the class which will execute when Alarm triggers, here we have
    // given AlarmReciever in the Intent, the onRecieve() method of this class will execute when
    // alarm triggers and
    //we will write the code to send SMS inside onRecieve() method pf Alarmreciever class
    Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverNotification.class);

    // create the object
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    //set the alarm for particular time
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMilliseconds , PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Scheduled for Tomorrow", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyAlarmService.class);
    intent.putExtra("Time", timeInMilliseconds);
    startService(intent);

    boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0,
            new Intent("com.ms.t.tms.MY_UNIQUE_ACTION"),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);

    if (alarmUp)
    {
        Log.d("myTag", "Alarm is already active");
    }
```

My receiver class:

```
 public class MyAlarmService extends IntentService {

        private NotificationManager mManager;
        Notification notification;
        Intent intent;

        public MyAlarmService() {
            super("MyAlarmService");
        }

        /**
         * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
         *
         * @param name Used to name the worker thread, important only for debugging.
         */
        public MyAlarmService(String name) {
            super(name);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {



        }

        @Override
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
            super.onStart(intent, startId);




                Log.d("Pana", "Alarm is triggered");

                Long time = intent.getLongExtra("Time", 0);

                mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);

                notification = new Notification(R.mipmap.ic_launcher,"This is a test message!", time);
                intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this.getApplicationContext(),0, intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(), "AlarmManagerDemo", "This is a test message!", pendingNotificationIntent);

                mManager.notify(0, notification);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are not setting time to past?

Comment: `timeInMilliseconds` might not be correct, check it properly.

Comment: Yes.. I have checked with online date to milli converter and milli to date converter. One more thing is if date is set for tomorrow in the notification displayed application displays tomorrows date but notification is displayed instantly

Comment: Yes I have checked it.

Comment: Google calendar app also shows instant notification ?

Answer (score 3):

Faced same problem but finally able to solve it.

In my case i was supplying wrong month while parsing with `SimpleDateFormat`

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

You can check weather your `timeInMilliseconds` is correct or not using

```
Log.i(TAG, "Date in milli :: " + timeInMilliseconds);  

Log.i(TAG,"System.currentTimeMillis() = "+System.currentTimeMillis());
```

if `timeInMilliseconds` is less than `System.currentTimeMillis()` then `timeInMilliseconds` is wrong else correct.

In this **M** is **month in year** starting from **1 to 12**

In my case i was supplying month starting from **0 to 11**

To solve this issue i incremented month by 1 and then parsed with `SimpleDateFormat` and problem solved.

Comment: These are my values from log:

Date in milli :: 1427179200000
 System.currentTimeMillis() = 1427178834352

When I setted the alarm current time was 12:03 pm and time to which alarm set was 12:10 pm but as soon as I  set Notification is displayed.

Comment: Month one I think I ma ok with that, because I am considering the date and time entered by the user using date and time picker. If i try the validation as  specified in answer 1 I don get the notification only. Not understanding what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your notification is displayed as soon as you are binding your service `MyAlarmService` because you are showing notification in `onStartCommand()` method

You should pass `Calender` object to `MyAlarmService` so that you can show notification at that specific time. You can refer to [here](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/notification-for-a-user-chosen-time/)

Comment: Ok I feel this will help me. Where can I show the notification other than onStart() command?

Comment: You should add checking like `(intent.getBooleanExtra(INTENT_NOTIFY, false))` for example before calling `mManager.notify(0, notification);` so that the notification do not come as soon as you bind your service

Comment: In the link which you have referred, notification method is called in onStartCommand() method only right..

Comment: I did that now alarm notification is not getting displayed as soon as it is set and also even for the time set it is not displaying notification. why is that happening? It should display the alarm for the time it is set right?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to set Alarm using Alarm Manager class. Just keep in mind that your unique id should different and time should in millisecond.

```
int uniqueId = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() & 0xfffffff);

AlarmManager mAlarm = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this
                                .getSystemService(MainActivity.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
ArrayList<PendingIntent> intentArray = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();


// Unique id should be different all the time. So I used it with System current Millis seconds.

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this,
                                    uniqueId, intentR, 0);


// Give you time in milliseconds for the Alarm. I given Alarm time after 1 minute (1 * 60 * 10000

mAlarm.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, systemTime + 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
                                    pendingIntent);

intentArray.add(pendingIntent);
```